# '-' в регулярных выражениях

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь проверить число, например *-42*, вроде как, в `alert` должно быть написано только это число, но пишется `-42,-`. Как сделать так чтоб второй минус не появлялся?

```js
var task = '-42';
var t2 = task.match(/(\-|\+)\d+$/);
alert(t2);
```

Comment: Нет, по задумке может быть написано так: "X-42"

Comment: круглые скобки, выделающие группу незачем. перечисление символов короче в квадратных скобках `/[-+]\d+$/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Можно прикрепить индекс

```js
var task = '-42';
var t2 = task.match(/(\-|\+)\d+$/)[0];
alert(t2);
```

2) Задаём `+` или `-` в не запоминающихся скобках

```js
var task = '-42';
var t2 = task.match(/(?:\-|\+)\d+$/);
alert(t2);
```

Comment: Извините, а можно поподробней, что за индекс записи? А если будет так: "-42-3+4"?

Comment: @Alex3214, я второй вариант выложил

Comment: Спасибо, второй помог

Comment: @Alex3214, если вам помог мой ответ, отметьте его как правильный

Answer (score 1):

Вы все сделали верно, просто результат возвращается в виде массива. В `t2[0]` содержится полное совпадение, а в `t2[1]` то что в скобках: `(\-|\+)`

```js
var task = '-42';
var t2 = task.match(/(\-|\+)\d+$/);
alert(t2[0]);
alert(t2[1]);
```